# Need to read registry value from both 32 bit and 64 bit machine Windows machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system, command-prompt

I need to read some registry values using a .cmd file. I am using the following command for that purpose.

```
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "tscFile"') do set "TSCFile=%%b"
```

The problem is that, when I install the software on 32 bit,the path for registry is :  `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest"` and when I install the software on 64 bit machine, the path becomes : `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Looptest"`

Is there a way to read keys without knowing the version of OS?

Of course I know that initially I can check for the OS version and then can write the code accordingly. But, other than that, is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use a batchfile and detect your architecture to use "SYSNATIVE" directory. I think you can't avoid a pre-detection routine when using REG from a batch script. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/8cf5110c-3a57-4c78-b52c-ee7c04e8fc85/reg-query-pointing-to-wow6432node-instead-of-the?forum=configmgrgeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting an idea from RGuggisberg's answer, I changed my code like this :

```
@echo off 

set replacementString=
if defined Programfiles(x86) set "replacementString=Wow6432Node\"


FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\%replacementString%Looptest" /v "tscFile"') do set "TSCFile=%%b"

echo %TSCFile%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do REQ QUERY /? and notice the /reg:32 and /reg:64 switches. Then add something like this to the beginning of your bat file (before you do any reg operations) so that it works on 32 or 64 bit machines.

```
set "Reg32="
set "Reg64="
if defined Programfiles(x86) set "Reg64=/reg:64" & set "Reg32=/reg:32"
```

This has the added advantage that you can specify either 32 bit or 64 bit registry area on 64 bit machines by using the appropriate Regnn variable for your registry operations. Assuming you want the 64 bit registry area when you are on a 64 bit machine your example would then become:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "tscFile" %Reg64%') do set "TSCFile=%%b"
```

And since %Reg64% is not defined on a 32 bit machine, you code will work correctly there too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. Though this did not completely solved my problem, but definitely this answer helped to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Windows x64 Versions will automatically decide to read from Wow6432 node when running 32 bit processes (transparent redirect). So if you could make sure your command is run in a 32 bit process, you could rely on that mechanism and would not have to bother with the Wow6432 node.

If your command runs as 64 bit process, you have to look for the right place by yourself.

You could run a 32 bit cmd on a 64 bit windows by calling `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`. Unfortunately, the SysWoW64 folder is missing on 32 bit windows, so you have to make the decision one step earlier...